# My PHP code to produce XML document is not working right

Tags: php, xml

I want to create/produce XML document from PHP, but not working.

I have this code right here:

```
<?php
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement("<evalues></evalues>");
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){     
        $evalue = $xml->addChild('evalue', $row[1]);
        $evalue->addAttribute('id', $row[0]);            
    }
    echo $xml->saveXML();
?>
```

the result looks like this, in one long line

```
1513971901.549931756795512.970022842372553.270163414774046.390384216874570.370032821081734.920144539784.98
```

The source code looks like this, which is correct, but I want it to look like below in the browser as an XML document without having to view the source code.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<evalues>
    <evalue id="5">1513971901.54993</evalue>
    <evalue id="6">1756795512.97002</evalue>
    <evalue id="7">2842372553.27016</evalue>
    <evalue id="8">3414774046.39038</evalue>
    <evalue id="9">4216874570.37003</evalue>
    <evalue id="10">2821081734.92014</evalue>
    <evalue id="11">4539784.98</evalue>
</evalues>
```

Right now when i right click on the page and click Save Page As, it shows .htm at the end BUT i want it to show .xml

Answer (score 3):

Just give your client a proper content type:

```
header('Content-Type: text/xml');
```

Comment: Can you tell me exactly where to put it? inside the PHP? Do I need echo?

Comment: @Pheap: put it at the top of your php-file, right after `<?php`. No, you don't need `echo`, just copy-paste my line as-is.

Comment: I have tried to put it everywhere but I got a warning and it still show the same thing, just one line. It said,"Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by ... on line (line number)". Where line number is the header('Content-Type:text/xml') is. Anymore suggestion?

Comment: @Pheap: which warning? I've forgot my magic sphere to read your minds at home.

Answer (score 1):

You should set the header content type to text/xml so that the browser could identify that the document is an xml document.

```
header('Content-Type: text/xml');
```

You should put this code before anything is outputted to the document. That is before any echo of print statement. In this case you case put the code before the loop.

Since there is no stylesheet attached to your xml document Internet Explorer may still display it as a plain text file. You can see the document as it is using **Mozilla Firefox**.

Comment: It actually still display as one line in Mozilla Firefox. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to actually use the XML (just display it), change your last line to

```
echo '<pre>', htmlspecialchars($xml->saveXML()), '</pre>';
```